# How to solve the SSL error when downloading files in python?

Tags: python, ssl-certificate

I want to download a pdf file with:

async def get_file(url, folder, session):

```
filename = folder.strip('\\') + '\\' + str(datetime.datetime.now()).replace(':', '_') + '.pdf'

async with session.get(url, headers = headers) as resp:
    if resp.status == 200:
        f = await aiofiles.open(filename, mode='wb')
        await f.write(await resp.read())
        await f.close()

async def download_pdf(urls, folder):
    connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=60)
    semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(10)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with semaphore:
            async with ClientSession(connector=connector, headers=headers) as session:
                tasks = [get_file(url, folder, session) for url in urls]
                result = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

urls = ['https://www.ttzqnews.com/uploads/soft/1712/2-1G219152559.pdf']
directory = r'C:\data'
asyncio.run(download_pdf(urls, directory))
```

I received the following error.

```
SSL error in data received
protocol: <asyncio.sslproto.SSLProtocol object at 0x00000280B59C1CC0>
transport: <_SelectorSocketTransport closing fd=4304 read=idle write=<idle, bufsize=0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 526, in data_received
    ssldata, appdata = self._sslpipe.feed_ssldata(data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 189, in feed_ssldata
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 763, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)
```

I added the `pip.ini` file but it cannot solve the problem.

What should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: The servers SSL certificate is invalid. It has expired: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.ttzqnews.com&latest

Comment: Then what should I do?

Comment: I changed `https` to `http` and it worked